# Getting 302 redirects on any service that i redeploy

Tags: cloudflare, google-cloud-run

We're suddenly getting recursive 302 redirects in our Cloud Run services. Any service that we deploy now will get the same issue.

We run a small app of like 8 services with Cloud Run and recently one of those started being inaccessible due to 302 redirects. Any service we have re-deployed in the last 40 minutes has the same issue.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried wit another google cloud project and get the same results, very different services.

Comment: UPDATE: This only happens if I access the service through the domain mappings. if we try to access the  https://***.a.run.app link it works.

Comment: Can you explain how you're doing redirects? It is recommended that you use relative paths in the `Location` header if you're redirecting within the same host. If your `https://` endpoint keeps redirecting to `http://` you'll get this loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of August 28th, Cloud Run now only accepts HTTPS requests in every region. HTTP requests receive a 302 redirect.

The following Mandatory Service Announcement was sent and contains more information:

> Hello Google Cloud Run Customer,
>
> We are writing to let you know that in order to make Cloud Run secured
>   by default, Cloud Run services will only be accessible via HTTPS.
>
> What do I need to know? Any HTTP requests to Cloud Run services will
>   receive a 302 "Moved Temporarily" status code that redirects to the
>   HTTPS location. Web browsers follow this redirection.
>
> Requests to Cloud Run services invoked via HTTP from clients which do
>   not follow 302 redirects will start failing. To avoid any service
>   disruption, please ensure your Cloud Run services are invoked using
>   HTTPS (URLs that start with ‘https://’). This applies to both
>   *.run.app endpoints and endpoints using custom domains.
>
> What do I need to do? If your Cloud Run service is invoked via HTTP
>   from clients that do not follow redirects, please ensure the clients
>   making the requests use HTTPS by August 19, 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Steren. Is there a way to restart SSL certificate generation for existing domain mappings (>1 month)?.

Asking because now that I know that CloudRun will only allow HTTPS connections I will need to make my DNS (Cloudflare) use Full(strict) or Full SSL mode. 

However, given my domain-mappings don't have certificates it fails on the handshake. If I could retrigger my certificate generation I could be in a good place.

Comment: Deleting and recreating the domain mapping should re-generate a certificate

Comment: Tried recreating the Domain Mapping but Cloudflare still struggles to do a SSL Handshake with Google and just 525s :(

Comment: After almost 3 years of working without any problem Google Cloud Run stopped renewing certificates. It seems there are some ACME requests that are redirected so that the handshake can't complete. Just stay away from this shitshow named google cloud. Forever an alpha product. `2023-09-25 17:38:03.517 EEST
GET302 0 B 0 ms Google-Certificates-Bridge  http://[redacted]/.well-known/acme-challenge/sDLP4FY7aXtYudhowJ0TqNLuyy99O4sIWb2K-mq_NBA761I4lyX2b6Zd2vf8Um53`